# C# get access to caller in parent constructor

Tags: c#

I have a child and a parent class, as such:

```
class B : A{
    public B : base(){
    // stuff
    }
}



class A{
    public A(){

    // how can I gain access here to the class that called me, 
    // ie the instance of class B that's being instantiated.

     }  
}
```

As above, my question is whether I can see who called the parent constructor within the constructor of the parent class.

One way to do this would be to have a separate function in `A` to which you pass `this` from within B. Is there anything simpler, ie can I do this during object initialization, or is that too early in the object construction process ? Does the whole object `B` need to be "ready" before I can access it from within `A` ?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to see this? What problem are you trying to solve that needs this solution?

Comment: You can't. That's a violation of OOP principle BTW.

Comment: In general, a child class should have no idea about it's parent class or it makes it very hard to uphold the Open Closed Principle (OCP)

Comment: +1 on @Lasse's comment.  If you edit to tell us what you would like to do, we can help you find a better OO solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Within `A`, it's easy - you just use `this` and cast it to `B` if you're confident that it really *is* a `B` rather than any other derived class. The object will already an instance of `B`.

However, it's generally a *bad* idea to call virtual methods from constructors, as the body of the B constructor hasn't been run yet, so it's only half-initialized. I've had a few situations where this is a pain, but if you tell us what you're trying to achieve we may be able to come up with something cleaner.

Comment: Actually, this answers my question well! Totally forgot I can just cast to B. But as you said, that seems like a very hacky and uncertain way, considering the constructor is still executing. I'm abandoning this idea and doing something simpler that will work for me! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can check what the type is which is being instantiated:

```
public A()
{
  var theType = this.GetType(); // will be typeof(B) in your example
}
```

But acessing the instance (e.g. it's properties) is probably not wise, since the derived type is not yet initialized when the base type's constructor is executing.